# WordPressに導入文の投稿フォームを追加する方法

Tags: wordpress

WordPressに以下の画像のような、導入文の投稿フォームを追加するには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

カスタムフィールドの追加はプラグインを使用するとfunctions.phpを編集せずに簡単にできます。
プラグインは沢山あるので、'カスタムフィールドの追加はプラグイン'とかキーワードにして検索して目的にあったプラグインを選定してください。

しかし、以下にプラグインを使わない方法を書きます。
テーマのfunctions.phpへ以下のコードを追加するとtextareaのカスタムフィールドを追加できます。
functions.phpを編集する前にfunctions.phpのバックアップを取ってから慎重に行いましょう。

```
function _add_field()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'field-name',//入力id
        '導入文',//表示タイトル
        '_addmetabox',//コールバック関数名
        'post'//screen
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', '_add_field' );

function _addmetabox( $post )
{
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'introduction_sentence', true);
    echo '<textarea name="introduction_sentence" style="width: 100%;height: 200px">'.$value.'</textarea>';
//    wp_editor( $value, 'introduction_sentence' );
    wp_nonce_field( 'nonce_key', 'namenonce' );
}

function _save_field( $post_id )
{
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'namenonce' ] )
    || ! check_admin_referer( 'nonce_key', 'namenonce' )
    ){ return $post_id;}

    update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            'introduction_sentence',
            $_POST['introduction_sentence']
    );
    return $post_id;
}
add_action( 'save_post', '_save_field' );
```